# Papersize in latex

Tags: paper-size, dvips, ps2pdf

I am using Windows 8, Texmaker 4.5 and Miktex 2.9.

When compiling Latex, `Dvi2ps` and `ps2pdf`, I have a problem of papersize. My miktex option is A4 Paper. When compiling, the dvi and ps files are a4, but the pdf is letter. I use the option `ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE#a4 %.ps %.pdf` which does not change anything.

When compiling pdflatex I do have a4 paper.

Could you help me get a A4 paper when using ps2pdf ?

Thank you

Comment: Confused by this... Are you setting paper size in your `LaTeX` code? for example, the package `geometry` can do that.

Comment: You should use `-sPAPERSIZE=a4`.

Comment: @Werner: not for a Windows user

Comment: I am using the package geometry, and setting the paper size in obvious places :
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

Comment: \usepackage[dvips,a4paper]{geometry}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it is solved by comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvips,a4paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    foo
\end{document}
```

has a4 in the pdf:

```
voss@shania:~$ pdfinfo zz.pdf
Title:          zz.dvi
Creator:        dvips(k) 5.996 Copyright 2016 Radical Eye Software
Producer:       GPL Ghostscript 9.18
CreationDate:   Tue Dec 20 20:02:50 2016
ModDate:        Tue Dec 20 20:02:50 2016
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595 x 842 pts (A4)
Page rot:       0
File size:      3846 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

If your DVI configuration has the letter format preset, then you may need a

```
dvips -t unknown filename.dvi
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work. I get the pdf :

Comment: PDF Producer:      MikteX GPL Ghostscript 9.05
PDF Version : 1.4
Page Size : 8.50 x 11.00 in

Comment: try `dvips -t unknown filename.dvi` and then `ps2pdf filename.ps`

Comment: Look at the `.ps` file, line 9 or so. You should have `DocumentPaperSizes: a4`. B.t.w., you should update MiKTeX: present version of MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript is `9.19`.